# Finding substring in a given string by changing into char array

Tags: java

i am working on the following program. but its not giving me the correct output for string "nameiskhan" and substring as"name".
i know this might be a duplicate question but i couldn't find the desired answer in those questions.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.String;

public class CheckingSubstring2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a String: ");
    String string1 = input.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter a second String: ");
    String substring = input.next();
    if (isSubstring(string1, substring)) {
        System.out.println("The second string is a substring of the first.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("The second string is NOT a substring of the first.");
    }
}   
public static boolean isSubstring(String string1, String substring) {
    char c[]=string1.toCharArray();
    char d[]=substring.toCharArray();
    boolean match = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d.length; j++) {
            if (c[i] == d[j]) {
                match = true;
            } else {
                match = false;
            }   
        }
   }
    return match;

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to do it without `contains`, how about this?

What I do here is that going through the original string one pass and check if the `substring` can be found as consecutive characters in the main `String`.

```
public static boolean isSubstring(String string1, String substring) {
    char c[]=string1.toCharArray();
    char d[]=substring.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        if(c[i] == d[0]){
            boolean match = false;
            for(int j = 0; j < d.length; j++){
                if(c[i+j] != d[j]){
                    match = false;
                    break;
                } else{
                    match = true;
                }
            }

            if(match)   return true;
        }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @thebrightshadow It was a fault in my logic when we have two consecutive letters the same. Fixed it

Comment: this works fine for letters repeating twice. It does not work in case of repeating letters more than once in a substring

Comment: Can you give an example scenario?

Comment: this  is not an actual word.. but for the sake of testing i took it. "khallllllliiiiii" and "llii"

Comment: Seems like this cannot be done in one pass. Changed it to use 2 for loops. This should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest becoming familiar with different debugging techniques.  A very quick and easy one is a print statement.  For example, you can print the values that you are comparing to make sure it looks reasonable.  It will also give you an indication of how many times your loop is running.  Stepping through the algorithm, the first two characters to be compared are c[0] = 'n' and d[0] = 'n'. That's good. The next two are c[0] = 'n' and d[1] = 'a'. That's not. Also, I assume you intend for the program to stop running if it finds a substring, but it doesn't appear that it would do so.  Likewise, you might consider not comparing every element of the substring if a comparison has already been false.